# Parametrized query not resolving sql injection flaws

Tags: sql, sql-injection, veracode

I have the following piece of code, in which I have made the parameterized query, as I read somewhere that this avoids the SQL injection. But after making this change, I am still getting the SQL injection flaw.

```
StrCmd = "select TdsSubCode from Rate where TdsCode= @cboTdsCode and DSCode= @cboDedStatus"

dsCmd = New SqlCommand(StrCmd, conTdsPac)

dsCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

dsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cboTdsCode", cboTdsCode.Text)

dsCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cboDedStatus", cboDedStatus.Text)

dsCmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: And what flaw is that?

Comment: Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an SQL Command ('SQL Injection')

Comment: Assuming it is not a false positive, it might in some way be unhappy about the use of `.AddWithValue`. You can use `.Add` and specify the parameter type to avoid the computer having to guess what the parameter type is.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for your response. In case of .Add, we can specify the parameter type but then how to assign the value. I can use: dsCmd.Parameters.Add("@cboTdsCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar). How would i need to assign the value of "cboTdsCode.Text" to parameter "@cboTdsCode"

Comment: @Bordan You can use the form `sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@x", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = "hkj"`.

Comment: Why do you believe this is vulnerable to SQL injection? What did you try that showed that the vulnerability?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: I will give that a try. appreciate your help.

Comment: @WernerHenze: I uploaded the code in veracode and it showed me the vulnerability.

Comment: @Bordan I believe it is a false positive. Can you try to exploit it when giving for example `cboTdsCode.Text='3;DELETE * FROM rate; --'`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Unfortunately the solution of using .Add did not work.

Comment: WernerHenze: choTdsCode.Text is an example. Sql Injection also occurs in different instances, like:              \r\n                                                       select count(cocd) from  transactions where voucherNo = @strVno        cmdTran.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strVno", strVno)

Comment: In the above example, there is no use of .Text, and still sql injection flaw pops up.

Comment: @Bordan Veracode claim a false positive rate of "less than 15%". Which is easily enough to suppose you are getting false positives. Have you contacted Veracode? I expect they would like to be informed so that they can improve their product.

Comment: I realize this question is over 3 years old but I would argue this is a false positive from Veracode.  Our scan yelled at us about parameterized sql using a stored procedures.  It's ridiculous!